# WatchConnectivity - transerUserInfo is sending, but not receiving data

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, watchconnectivity

I've been making an app that uses WatchConnectivity to transfer a simple struct from the Apple Watch to iPhone, and have been running into some troubles. Sending is perfectly fine, and both devices are reachable and activated on the same session, but the iPhone never seems to receive the struct I send it.

Here's my current code. I decided to use `transferUserInfo` to allow background transfer of data.

The struct:

```
struct myDataList {
    var xAcc: [Int]
    var timestamps: [Int]
}
```

Watch (Sending):

```
func sendTestData(data:myDataList) {
    print("sending file to iphone")
    if WCSession.default.activationState == WCSessionActivationState.activated && WCSession.isSupported() && WCSession.default.isReachable {
        WCSession.default.transferUserInfo(["Data" : data])
    }
    else {
        print("Could not send")
    }
}
```

iPhone (Receiving):

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : Any] = [:]) {
    print("received something")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let data = userInfo["Data"] as? myDataList {
            for (acc,time) in zip(data.xAcc,data.timestamps){
                let dataLine: String = "\(acc),\(time)\n"
                self.appendToFile(file: "data", data: dataLine)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On both devices I've started a session like so:

```
if WCSession.isSupported() {
    WCSession.default.delegate = self
    WCSession.default.activate()
}
```

I've tested the other functions to write to file/etc and they are working individually. I'd appreciate feedback and advice on how to resolve this. Cheers!

Comment: Have you checked `userInfo`? What does it contain?

Comment: I can't check `userInfo` as the `session` function doesn't even seem to get called. I added several lines above the `DispatchQueue` closure to print to the screen and console and they're not printing. Ideally `userInfo` would be the struct, from which I'm trying to extract the arrays.